# certified pdf C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

How can i create certified pdf with c#?

Comment: First off, please explain what "certified pdf" means - possibly a link to the definition.

Comment: Hi Oded :)
http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/certified-pdf
thanks for your attention.

Comment: it seems clear from that page that you need to use one of the certified/license products that they mention.

Comment: Already answered by mkl Check the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484094/itextsharp-digital-sign-and-show-infosubject-and-issuername-of-certificate-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certified PDF is basically a PDF that has been digitally signed using a certificate that is trusted by the Adobe Root Certificate. This service is called [Adobe Certified Document Services](http://www.adobe.com/security/partners_cds.html). When your document is signed it displays a blue ribbon at the top and verifies that the document is from you and it hasn't been tampered with.
[image]

You can get the certificate from a participant of the service, we use one called [GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.co.uk/document-security-compliance/adobe-cds/)

Once you have the certificate you need to get a device to actually sign the documents, this can be a USB stick that you plug into your PC or a PCI HSM card that sits in a server for high volume signing.

Once you have this in place your PDF's will display the blue ribbon

In our system we used [Morphon Tom](http://www.morphon.com/tom/) to actually sign the PDFs, it's a webservice that you simply send a PDF to and it returns it signed using your certificate.

Hope this gets you started!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting component for PDF signing:

- Signing using smart cards and cryptographic tokens
- CAdES signatures
- LTV signatures
- Multisigning

[docs](http://-Signing%20using%20smart%20cards%20and%20cryptographic%20tokens%20-CAdES%20signatures%20-LTV%20signatures%20-Multisigning%20https://docs.apitron.com/Digital_signatures_in_PDF)

Comment: Your link doesn't work. And your enumeration does not mention whether your solution can create certification signatures or merely approval signatures.